# dataframe merge based on three matching columns

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

Thank you for helping, I really have trouble with the merge of dataframes (I wanna merge two frames with the following conditions) ,however it fails "Unintended result in merged dataframes yellow-highlighted in picture 3).

I wanna merge based on the first two columns. For row,
1). If column one and two in the two frames matched together. --> then combine into a single row.
2). If either column one or two do not match in the two frames , but the other one matched --> create a new row.
3). If both column one and two do not match in the two frames  --> create a new row.

Dataframe (1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAp3c.png)

Dataframe (2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ0Cx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99h9L.png)

Comment: Main problem is " in the last picture, the merged dataframes showing incorrect result for date 2022-05-01 and 2022-04-30 with two rows showing different numbers even though the first two conditions are exactly the same. How to fix" Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). And please provide a MRE (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying a list of columns to merge on.

```
Output_list_sort[0].merge(Output_list_sort[1], on=['省市', '市', '類型'], how='inner')
```